# Render video texture data from iOS to unity Texture2d on every update

Tags: unity-game-engine, dji-sdk, texture2d

Background : 
I am creating an application where i am using Dji SDK for iOS.
I have integrated the SDK and i am able to register the app of DJI.
I am able to get the drone connection and model name.

Next, i intend to do start the video stream on drone using the sdk and 
capture the same on mobile screen. But there is a twist.

Setup :
My application is unity based and intend to use some features of unity. 
Therefore, the data that i get from dji sdk on this method

```
-(void)videoFeed:(nonnull DJIVideoFeed *)videoFeed didUpdateVideoData:(nonnull NSData *)videoData{
    [[DJIVideoPreviewer instance] push:(uint8_t *)videoData.bytes length:(int)videoData.length];
```

is required to be sent to unity where i would render it in Texture2d, provided by unity.

Problem : 
I am not able to convert the videoData present in above method and send it in a format 
that unity can understand and render in Texture2d object.

I got some suggestion related to _GetNativeTexturePtr and MTLTexture, but it didn't work for me.

Objective : transfer NSData * videoData from iOS to unity Texture2d object on every update() function called and render it there.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks !

To give more clear understanding, i am sharing how i have done in Android (it works in android) :

```
static Texture2D videoStreamTexture;
protected override Texture2D StartVideoStream_Native() {
    int width = droneNativeObject.Get<int>("width");
    int height = droneNativeObject.Get<int>("height");

    if (videoStreamTexture == null)
        videoStreamTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

    droneNativeObject.Call("StartStream", videoStreamTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr().ToInt32()/*, 1920, 1088*/);
    return videoStreamTexture;
}

protected override void StopVideoStream_Native() {
    droneNativeObject.Call("StopStream");
   /* if (videoStreamTexture != null) {
        UnityEngine.Object.DestroyImmediate(videoStreamTexture);
        videoStreamTexture = null;
    }*/
}

public override void Update() {
    base.Update();

    if (IsStreaming && droneNativeObject != null &&videoStreamTexture != null) {
        var frame = droneNativeObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("GetCameraFrame");
        if (frame == null)
            return;

        byte[] bytes = frame.Get<byte[]>("jpegFrame");
        int width = frame.Get<int>("width");
        int height = frame.Get<int>("height");


        if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0) {
            //Debug.Log("texture size: width " + videoStreamTexture.width + " height " + videoStreamTexture.height);
            videoStreamTexture.LoadRawTextureData(bytes);
            videoStreamTexture.Apply(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Native Android code :

```
 public int width = 1280;
public int height = 720;

public void StartStream(int textureId/*,int textureWidth, int textureHeight*/){
    if(isStreaming)
        return;

    isStreaming = true;

    cameraFrameIndex = -1;
    lastPublishedCameraFrameIndex = -1;

    if(surfaceTexture == null)
        surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textureId);
    //surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(width, height);

    SetCameraToRecordMode();
    if(codecManager == null)
        codecManager = new DJICodecManager(activity.getBaseContext(), surfaceTexture, width, height);

    VideoFeeder.getInstance().provideTranscodedVideoFeed().addVideoDataListener(videoDataListener);
} 
public final class CameraFrame{

        public byte[] jpegFrame;
        public int width;
        public int height;

        public CameraFrame(){

        }

        public CameraFrame(byte[] frameData, int width, int height){
            this.jpegFrame = frameData;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

    CameraFrame jpegFrame;
    public CameraFrame FGetCameraFrame(){
        if(!isStreaming || lastPublishedCameraFrameIndex == cameraFrameIndex){
            return null;
        }

        lastPublishedCameraFrameIndex = cameraFrameIndex;

        byte[] bytes = codecManager.getRgbaData(width, height);
        return new CameraFrame(bytes, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get any response here eve after adding so much info.

Comment: Did you check out the sample code of the VideoFrameProcessor in the DJISDKDemo? It allows you to get a UIImage from a frame, which you should be able to turn into a Unity Texture2D. For OBJ-C it's in  Sample Code/ObjcSampleCode/DJISdkDemo/Demo/Camera/fpv/CameraFPVViewController.m. It was added after a decoding info request here: https://github.com/dji-sdk/DJIWidget/issues/8 I hope this helps!